Is there any way to turn on bluetooth using cmd line (adb shell preferably)
I tried turning on bluetooth using cmd bluetooth_manager enable:

But i see its failing a check in BluetoothManagerService.java::checkIfCallerIsForegroundUser
Since the caller is shell (UID 2000).
So Framework is not allowing to turn on Bluetooth
====================================

Also tried using service call bluetooth_manager 3 (call for enable api)

This is failing on Null pointer reference call from BluetoothManager
====================================
Tried with adb shell am start -a android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_ENABLE

This is asking for allow or deny permission, it can be automated but i am looking for any other options if there are

Enabling Bluetooth via adb shell without user interaction or root access is restricted by Android's security policies. Here's why your attempts fail and alternatives:
Why Attempts Fail Below Reasons

bluetooth_manager enable: Fails due to BluetoothManagerService enforcing checkIfCallerIsForegroundUser, blocking non-foreground users like adb shell.
service call bluetooth_manager 3: Likely triggers a NullPointerException since required states or dependencies aren't initialized.
adb shell am start: Shows a permission dialog that requires user action.

Alternatives

Automate the Dialog: Use adb or tools like uiautomator to simulate button presses (adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER).
Root Access: If rooted, enable Bluetooth with:


adb root


adb shell service call bluetooth_manager 6


Custom App: A system-signed app can use BluetoothAdapter.enable() without user interaction.
Developer Options: Relax restrictions with "Disable Permission Monitoring" (only for development devices).

Without root, automation or creating a privileged app is your best option.

well, you can do it programmatically with enable() method
yes, its deprecated and not working when targetting app for API33+

Note: For applications targeting Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU or above, this API will always fail and return false. If apps are targeting an older SDK (Build.VERSION_CODES.S or below), they can continue to use this API.

so use targetSdk = 32 - write an simple app with some Activity or ForegroundService starting bluetooth. with adb you can push this app into device, set perms, run your code with some Intent and if needed uninstall
adb install -r your_apk.apk

adb shell pm grant your.package.name android.permission.BLUETOOTH
adb shell pm grant your.package.name android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
adb shell pm grant your.package.name android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN // API 31 / Android 12+
adb shell pm grant your.package.name android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT // API 31 / Android 12+

// run whatever is carrying your enable() call
adb shell am start -n your.package.name/.gui.activity.MainActivity

// after a while, when bluetooth job done
adb uninstall your.package.name

